# Align TextView width inside a custom Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-custom-view

this is my first time on stackoverflow.

I'm not a native English speaker, so if you feel weird on my grammar please correct me, thanks.

My Question:

[image]

Please see my screenshot above, the spinner lists the network interfaces of my phone, and now their names and their IP addresses are not aligned.

Here is my spinner rows' layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/interface_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/interface_addr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to align the width of `@+id/interface_name` automatically, just like `TableLayout` and `TableRow`, I've tried replacing the `LinearLayout` as `TableRow` but no luck.

Maybe I have to fix the width of `@+id/interface_name`?

Thanks for advice, if you need something else, please tell me and I will update it.